# Splice items from array considering indexes from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array `input` and another array `indexes`. I want to remove item from array `input` whose index is provided in `indexes` array.

I have tried it using `array.splice` in `for loop` but as `item` is being removed in each iteration, indexes of other items are being changed.

**JavaScript**:

```
var array = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

indexes.forEach(function(item) {
  array.splice(item, 1);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and do the following:

```js
var array = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

array = array.filter(function(x, i) {
  return indexes.indexOf(i) === -1;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using forEach loop which give you the item as first argument and the index on second one, so as per my understanding what you want to do can achieve by this, try this hope this solve your problem :)

```
indexes.forEach(function(item, index) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Comment: **NO** It is invalid..`index` will return 0,1,2 hence it will remove items from those indexed per iteration..

Answer (score 0):

Sort the indexes array from high to low, then spice will only change the index of the numbers you have already removed